# Why is this inequality about unit vectors true?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working through Strang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra*. Problem Set 1.2, #24 starts,

> One-line proof of the inequality $|\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{U}|\le1$ for unit vectors $(u_1,u_2)$ and $(U_1,U_2)$:
>
> $$|\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{U}| \le |u_1||U_1| + |u_2||U_2| \le \frac{u_1^2+U_1^2}{2} + \frac{u_2^2+U_2^2}{2} = 1$$

I understand the first jump—making all the terms of a dot product positive must of course be greater than or equal to the original dot product.

But can someone explain the next jump?

Comment: Note that $(a-b)^2 \geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the AM-GM inequality it its simples form:$$a,b\geqslant0\implies\sqrt{ab}\leqslant\frac{a+b}2.$$

Comment: I see the resemblance but, squaring both sides, that would be $ab \le \frac{(a+b)^2}{4}$. How would he drop the $2ab$ term and increase the divisor to $2$?

Comment: It has *nothing* to do with squaring both sides. Take $a=u_i^{\,2}$ and $b=U_i^{\,2}$, and then$$\sqrt{ab}\leqslant\frac{a+b}2\iff|u_i||U_i|\leqslant\frac{u_i^{\,2}+U_i^{\,2}}2.$$

Comment: Ah, I should have thought of it in the reverse direction. Thank you!